# Cash Flow Forecast in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I am building a cash flow forecast in Power BI, and unfortunately it's not performing as expected. I am trying to create a table visualization, and then I will build a corresponding chart.

The table is currently showing:

[image]

However, I would expect:
[image]

I have a date master table which I am using to populate the "Cash Date" column. It looks like this:
[image]

The data in the Bank Balance table looks like this:
[image]

The data in the Bills table looks like this:
[image]

The data in the Invoices table looks like this:
[image]

Finally, I have checked my data relationships, and they seem to be appropriate:
[image]

Summary:
The first screenshot is what I am receiving when I create a table visualization in Power BI. The second screenshot is what I put together in Excel, outside of Power BI, and what I am trying to achieve based on the data in the Bank Balance, Bills and Invoices tables.

My original hypothesis, based on videos I've watched, was that my data relationship(s) was incorrect. However, based on the last screenshot that doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you please be more precise in what exactly is your intention, and the problem?

Comment: Can you please help me to understand the difference between the two screenshots? Second one has a grid view, and no Total row. Also in the first one, 'Bills' are negative, while in the second one is presented as a positive number. So, what from all of these are you trying to solve? From visual perspective and logical perspective?

Comment: The first screenshot is in Power BI. The second screenshot is in Excel. It was much easier for me to model exactly what I am trying to get at in Excel, hence the second screenshot. The purpose of the model is a cash flow forecast. To do a cash flow forecast, you take the beginning bank balance (Bank Balance), add in expected cash inflows (Invoices) and subtract expected cash outflows (Bills). Bills are negative in both the first and second one, Invoices are positive in both the first and second one.

Comment: As you will note in the Invoices table, there are rows with Cash Dates which fall outside the range of the dates on the Date Master. Hence, why the totals don't match.

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially if I understood well, you need to show the dates from both tables, from DateMaster, but also from other tables, event if there is no such date in the DateMaster?

If this is correct, try to [set up the relationship between the tables to be full outer join](https://radacad.com/how-to-change-joining-types-in-power-bi-and-power-query), which shows rows from both tables, and will show also the matching ones. 
That way you can have both dates